# Create trip number when a flag value changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as below

```
Ts-                                     Stat                                    
2021-03-06 10:36:22.000                 I
2021-03-06 10:37:22.000                 I
2021-03-06 10:38:22.000                 L
2021-03-06 10:39:22.000                 E
2021-03-06 10:40:22.000                 E
2021-03-06 10:41:22.000                 B
2021-03-06 10:42:22.000                 B
2021-03-06 10:43:22.000                 L
2021-03-06 10:44:22.000                 D
2021-03-06 10:45:22.000                 E
2021-03-06 10:46:22.000                 E
2021-03-06 10:47:22.000                 B
2021-03-06 10:48:22.000                 L
2021-03-06 10:49:22.000                 L
2021-03-06 10:50:22.000                 E
2021-03-06 10:51:22.000                 E
2021-03-06 10:52:22.000                 B
2021-03-06 10:53:22.000                 E
```

I want output as-

```
Ts-                                     Stat          Trip                
                                
2021-03-06 10:36:22.000                 I             NOtrip                  
2021-03-06 10:37:22.000                 I             Notrip
2021-03-06 10:38:22.000                 L             Notrip
2021-03-06 10:39:22.000                 E             Notrip
2021-03-06 10:40:22.000                 E             Notrip
2021-03-06 10:41:22.000                 B             Trip1
2021-03-06 10:42:22.000                 B             Trip1
2021-03-06 10:43:22.000                 L             Trip1
2021-03-06 10:44:22.000                 D             Trip1    
2021-03-06 10:45:22.000                 E             Trip1
2021-03-06 10:46:22.000                 E             Trip1
2021-03-06 10:47:22.000                 B             Trip2  
2021-03-06 10:48:22.000                 L             Trip2
2021-03-06 10:49:22.000                 L             Trip2
2021-03-06 10:50:22.000                 E             Trip2
2021-03-06 10:51:22.000                 E             Trip2
2021-03-06 10:52:22.000                 B             Trip3
2021-03-06 10:53:22.000                 E             trip3
```

means trip start when value changes (Stat) from E to B and end when stat Again changes from E TO B

after that final output should be as follows

```
trip   timetaken
Notrip   5 min(difference of time when notrip start and end)
Trip1    6 min(difference of time when trip1 start and end)
Trip2    5 min(difference of time when trip2 start and end)
Trip3    2 min(difference of time when trip3 start and end)
```

Kindly help me in this SQL Server query. I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 3):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT ts, 
                     stat, 
                     CASE WHEN stat = 'B' AND LAG(stat) OVER (ORDER BY ts) != 'B'
                          THEN 1
                          ELSE 0 END new_trip
              FROM [table] )
SELECT ts,
       stat,
       CASE WHEN SUM(new_trip) OVER (ORDER BY ts) = 0
            THEN 'No trip'
            ELSE 'Trip ' + CAST(SUM(new_trip) OVER (ORDER BY ts) AS CHAR)
            END trip
FROM cte
ORDER BY ts;
```

and

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT ts, 
                 stat, 
                 CASE WHEN (stat != 'B' OR LAG(stat) OVER (ORDER BY ts) = 'B') AND LAG(stat) OVER (ORDER BY ts) IS NOT NULL
                      THEN 0
                      ELSE 1 END trip_start,
                 CASE WHEN stat != 'E' OR LEAD(stat) OVER (ORDER BY ts) = 'E'
                      THEN 0
                      ELSE 1 END trip_end
          FROM [table] ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT ts,
                 stat,
                 trip_start,
                 trip_end,
                 SUM(trip_start) OVER (ORDER BY ts) - 1 trip_num
          FROM cte1
          WHERE trip_start + trip_end = 1 )
SELECT CASE WHEN trip_num = 0
            THEN 'No trip'
            ELSE 'Trip ' + CAST(trip_num AS CHAR)
            END trip,
       DATEDIFF(minute, MIN(ts), MAX(ts)) timetaken
FROM cte2
GROUP BY trip_num;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ba8b606a4f1d4ccb55d3e56976381209

Comment: Thanks Akina .and How to get the final output ?

Comment: @AkashSingh Updated.

Comment: Thank you so Much Akina  It is really very Helpful as I have  very basic knowledge about it .Thank you so much.